How do I make the /user/register form available in a twig template?
When comments in a (content type) Article are enabled, for an anonymous user Drupal 9.5 shows a text with links, "please regiter or login to post a comment". I would like the login form to be rendered there already, so that the user can login without leaving the article. For this, I would like to make the /user/register form available inside a twig template. How would I do that?

The login form is available as a block. You can simply configure it to be shown on articles.

Install Twig Tweak and try this: https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak-2x/cheat-sheet#s-drupal-form

You can also try this: https://mycode.blog/lakshmi/how-render-core-login-form-twig-template-drupal-8-and-drupal-9
